# CRAN submission works only on mac Keras. Architecture is 32bit however this version of Python is compiled for 64bit. Execution halted

Tags: python, r, keras, cran, submission

I am submitting a package to CRAN and recently got the email rejection saying that while it passed the mac check, it failed the Windows and Debian check. It seems to be a problem with finding keras (Debian) and having the wrong architecture (windows). Do I need to tell CRAN to install a different keras? Or a different python? Or something else?

Attached are the error files.

[Windows](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/LilRhino_0.1.0_20190123_075933/Windows/00check.log)

[Debian](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/LilRhino_0.1.0_20190123_075933/Debian/00check.log)

Comment: You can just email them and ask, They are friendly people and will know better than us. Latter you can come back here and answer your own question.

Comment: Will do! I'll come back when I've got an answer.